# Swift: how to make tab view controller button not show?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Ok, I have all my view controllers managed by a tab bar controller, and obviously when you connect in the storyboard the relationship between the controller and the Vcs as "view controller" a button appears on the tab bar. These are then accessible via the tab bar controller.

My problem is I need to have one VC be the in view controller array but NOT BE SHOWN IN A BUTTON on the tab bar. It should not be accessible to the user, but I need to be able to switch to that VC in code with `selectedIndex`

I do not know how to do this. I have tried disabling the button and doing

```
self.tabBar.items?[3].accessibilityElementsHidden = true
```

But the button is still there on the tab bar. How can I have the VC in the array of the tab bar controller but not shown in a button?

Comment: I understood your problem. Why can't remove view controller and insert it back?

Comment: Becuase even if you hide the tab bar won't rearrange tabs until you remove view controller.

Comment: I'm trying to understand "why" you're trying to do this?  What do you plan on happening to the active tab in the tab bar when you use this "hidden" VC?  I suspect that what you really want to do can be handled in another way, but I can't recommend a solution without the why.

Comment: I need this Because I need to trigger the switch programmatically but can't have the VC available at all times. Because sometimes the data hasn't been created yet for the VC to exist properly @ChrisAllwein

Comment: But once it "exists properly", you want it to show up as a button on the tab bar?

Comment: No. I will access it via a different button on the view that will appear/disappear accordingly

Comment: I just need to eliminate the tab button but keep them VC in the array. Would you know how to subclass or something as a solution?

Comment: *"I will access it via a different button on the view that will appear/disappear accordingly"* --- If it is not going to become a "new tab" then don't treat it as one of the TabBar controllers. Either swap it with the current view... or show it on top of the current view... or present it modally (if it's a view that you want to use and then dismiss)... **OR** explain what you actually want to do, rather than asking how to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the `UITabBarController` as is.

Not 100% sure on why you need to have a VC in that array but never visible on the bar, consider subclassing `UITabBarController` if thats the case.

Changes to the `viewControllers` or `items` property of a `UITabBarController` will encourage iOS to reload the Component and hence why you are seeing the VC in the TabBar.

Comment: How would I subclass for this? I need this Because I need to trigger the switch programmatically but can't have the VC available at all times. Because sometimes the data hasn't been created yet for the VC to exist properly